Custom reference list: Authors small caps, semicolon, year towards the end, title in quotation marks, no comma before volume, …
I am having problems formatting my reference list in accordance with my target journal requirements. I am (for now) using the apalike bibliography style, and I employ the natbib citation management package.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{tetlock2008more,
  title    = {More than words: Quantifying language to measure firms' fundamentals},
  author   = {Tetlock, Paul C. and Saar-Tsechansky, Maytal and Macskassy, Sofus},
  journal  = {Journal of Finance},
  volume   = {63},
  number   = {3},
  pages    = {1437--1467},
  year     = {2008},
  publisher= {Wiley Online Library}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}

The output I get is:

However, I need is:

I therefore need to do (for entries of type @article):

Authors in small caps
First-name initials come before last name for 2nd+ authors
Semicolon instead of comma as author-separator
Year not after author field but after volume
No comma between authors and title
Title in quotation marks
No comma before volume, don't print number.

Thank you so much for your support!

Welcome to TeX.SE. The custom-bib package, written by the author of the natbib citation management package, contains a utility called makebst, which lets you create bespoke bibliography styles. Open a commend window and type pdflatex makebst to get started. You'll be asked several dozen multiple-choice questions, each with a default choice. After you answer the question, you end up with a bespoke bst file.

By the way, the screenshots you posted seem to be wholly unconnected to the code you provided -- is this intentional? If it's not, please edit your posting to modify either the code or the screenshots. A separate concern: You've listed the formatting requirements for entries of type @article -- are there none for all other entry types?

You were right, I used the wrong code (I corrected that). And thank you for sharing your other concern. I only used the @article type as an example here, my actual main.tex file is much longer. But your answer helped me so much, thank you, Mico! I am amazed how well custom-bib works! It's amazing what tools people are developing for everyone to use...

You’re most welcome

I've taken the liberty of making your sample code truly minimal. Feel free to revert.
